# Setup SSL socket without authentication using boost::asio

Tags: c++, boost, ssl, boost-asio

I think this code is working though the server I want to connect to doesn't have their authentication working. I want to disable authentication checking but still connect using SSL? Here is the code:

```
    // Create a context that uses the default paths for
    // finding CA certificates.
    ssl::context ctx(ssl::context::sslv23);
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths();

    // Open a socket and connect it to the remote host.
    ssl_socket sock(io_service, ctx);
    tcp::resolver::query query(host_name_, "https");
    boost::asio::connect(sock.lowest_layer(), resolver_.resolve(query));
    sock.lowest_layer().set_option(tcp::no_delay(true));

    // Perform SSL handshake and verify the remote host's
    // certificate.
    sock.set_verify_mode(boost::asio::ssl::context::verify_none);

    //sock.set_verify_callback();
    //sock.set_verify_callback(ssl::rfc2818_verification(host_name_));
    sock.handshake(ssl_socket::client);
```

*How can I remove authentication checking?*

Comment: What do you mean authentication checking .. HTTP Basic authentication or SSL certificate authentication?

Comment: SSL certificate authentication

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking

Comment: try 
    openssl s_client -connect host:port

       this will tell you if their server is handshaking properly

Comment: Can you share the cod that connects to the server over SSL and how did you come up with the thought that your code is working well ? @user1064036